# What to do with ca.crt, name.crt, name.key, name.ovpn files?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I was given these four files to access the office's vpn server. I am on ubuntu 12.04, and am unsure how to began using these.
I tried using the vpn connection tab under the network connections, but my files didn't specify a username after importing and it forced to me to save one, so attempting to connect to it didn't yield any results.

What am I supposed to do with these four files to connect to the vpn?

Comment: The .ovpn file is the OpenVPN configuration file. The others are used by it, and should be in the same folder. I'm unfamilar with setting up OpenVPN on Ubuntu (or any vpn manager), but check that the package is installed and look for an option to import an OpenVPN configuration.

Answer (score 4):

`name.ovpn` is a text file with the OpenVPN client configuration. It should contain (among other things) something like the following lines.

```
ca ca.crt
cert name.crt
key name.key
```

Put files without a path in the same directory as `name.ovpn` (e.g. `/etc/openvpn` or `$HOME/foo`), and put files with a path in the specified directory. Start openvpn like this:

```
openvpn --config /PATH/TO/name.ovpn
```

If you're using `NetworkManager` try importing `name.ovpn` in the VPN tab of your network connection.